# Kafka server is on my local computer and my spark server is on aws, I am getting error "Failed to find data source: kafka."

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Kafka server is on my local computer and my spark server is on aws, I am trying to connect both. I am getting error "Failed to find data source: kafka."

-Spark server on aws

```
kafka_df = spark.readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
        .option("subscribe", "invoices") \
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
        .load() `
```

-Kafka producer server on local computer

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic invoices
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `spark-sql-kafka` package to your Spark driver(s).

For that error message, it doesn't matter where Spark or Kafka are running, however, `localhost` on AWS would not be able to connect to Kafka running on your own machine and you shouldn't expose Kafka insecurly over the open internet, if you were to connect the two.

Comment: `.config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.0") `

I added it to the driver, still the same error. I also tried changing `localhost` to my local computer ip address on my spark server, still the same error...

Any ideas?

Comment: I am desperate for a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what version of Spark you're using, but make sure you use the approriate version. Also, try using `--packages` to the Spark submit command. I've never had good success with altering the session config. And unclear what you mean by "local computer ip", but AWS cannot reach into your local (home) network without setting up port forwarding in your router; you would be better off running Kafka in EC2 or MSK

Comment: Thanks I had to add this `org.apache.spark  spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.7` to the spark-defaults.conf file in the spark home

Comment: And that fixed it?

Comment: yes, it did. but I had to install kafka on AWS.